# Need help deleting elements with special character @ from json object with jtc or jq

Tags: json, jq, jtc

I'm trying to identify object elements which a key starting with `@t`. My goal is to delete them from the object all together.

Example Input

```
{
  "process_state": {
    "@user_id": "john smith",
    "@t39ee396f50": 1,
    "@t375b0311e8": 1,
    "@t12dd92bf45": 1
     }
}
```

Expected Output

```
{
  "process_state": {
    "@user_id": "john smith",
     }
}
```

I've tried using jq and jtc to accomplish this and both seem to struggle with the leading @ symbol. I'm assuming it's a format issue with my code. Can I use wildcards? I've tried a couple methods with no luck.

JQ

jq '. |= map(select(. | contains("@t") | not))'

Error: and string ("@t") cannot have their containment checked

JTC

<file jtc -w'<process_state.@t*>l:'

No error but @t* fields still exist in json object.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're going to use `test("^@t")` instead of `contains("@t")` since we want to check for a *leading* `@t`. But that's not why you are getting that error. You have the wrong object on the left-hand side of `|=`, and `map` doesn't do what you think for objects.

Two solutions:

- Using filtering (like you were attempting):

  ```
  .process_state |= with_entries(
     select( .key | test("^@t") | not )
  )
  ```

  [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2LskhGpvhy) on jqplay
- Using deletion:

  ```
  .process_state |= del(
     .[
        keys_unsorted[] |
        select( test("^@t") )
     ]
  )
  ```

  [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Q1mjThmx1f) on jqplay

Answer (score 0):

This is correct `jtc` usage:

```
bash $ <file jtc -w'<^@t>L:' -p
{
   "process_state": {
      "@user_id": "john smith"
   }
}
bash $
```